# Another Doubt Regarding Brocard's Problem, Specifically about Where I Can Proceed after Prime Factorisation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, prime-factorization

I know this can draw downvotes as it's not a complete solution or sounds more like an opinion poll (or perhaps this must have appeared elsewhere, in which case you're free to let me know), but I would like to seek your help regrading this topic.

I decided to continue working on Brocard's problem (i.e., the number of integer solutions to the Diophantine equation $n! + 1 = m^2$), and here's where I have reached:

---

The currently available solutions are as follows (along with the $m+1$ and $m-1$ values; format : $(n,m,m+1,m-1)$):
$(4,5,6,4)$
$(5,11,12,10)$
$(7,71,72,70)$
From these, we can see $2 \mid m + 1$ and $3 \mid m + 1$ and $m+1$ increases by a product of powers of $2$ and $3$.Hence, we can conjecture( just because we haven't found any more of solutions) that $m+1$ is always of the form $m+1$ = $2^x3^y$, and thus $m-1$ = $2^x3^y-2$. Thus, we get $$n! = 2^x3^y(2^x3^y -2) = 2^{x+1}3^y(2^{x-1}3^y-1)\space(\text{equivalent to to} 2(m+1)\times \frac{(m-1)}2)\longrightarrow(1)$$ I conjecture that if any other solution existed, it should be of this form.

Notice that $(2^{x-1}3^y-1 = \frac{m-1}2 \equiv 1 \pmod{2})\land(2^{x-1}3^y-1 = \frac{m-1}2 \equiv 2 \pmod{3})\forall x = y \neq 1$, so only powers of odd primes other than $3$ are present in its prime factoristaion for greater $n$. Thus we can group the numbers in the factorials as follows:
$$4! = \color{red}{2^23}\times\color{blue}{2} = \color{red}{2(m+1)}\color{blue}{\frac{m-1}2}$$
$$5! = \color{red}{2^33}\times\color{blue}{5} = \color{red}{2(m+1)}\color{blue}{\frac{m-1}2}$$
$$7! = \color{red}{2^43^2}\times\color{blue}{5\times 7} = \color{red}{2(m+1)}\color{blue}{\frac{m-1}2}$$

[As of now the solutions to $x$ and $y$ for the available solutions are (format : $(n,x,y)$):
$(4,1,1)$
$(5,2,1)$
$(7,3,2)$
Apply these to the form at (1) and compare with the coloured ones]

And I believe that we have somehow grouped the numbers(reference:[thread at Unsolved Problems group in groups.io](https://groups.io/g/UnsolvedProblems/topic/85957921?p=%2C%2C%2C20%2C0%2C0%2C0%3A%3Arecentpostdate%2C%2C%2C20%2C2%2C0%2C0%2Cprevid%3D1633460994164822135%2Cnextid%3D1630431598514171568&previd=1633460994164822135&nextid=1630431598514171568&allview=1), first comment by Kermit Rose; not sure if those who aren't signed in can access this) even if not so effectively (perhaps), and..... this is where I get stuck.

---

I am not able to proceed further from here as I am still at the basics. I was adviced against using the available solutions to arrive at a conclusion by Kermit Rose, as I may end up thinking that no more cases existed. But I believe the introduction of $x$ and $y$ into the equation must have opened up more possibilities of enquiry. Still I wonder why I can't proceed... a helping hand would indeed be appreciated.

**PS**: I doubt if it's the abc conjecture at work that limits the solutions for $n, x$ and $y$.

#### Updates:

1. https://groups.io/g/UnsolvedProblems/message/12809 - another observation by Kermit Rose.
   From his claim, I conjectured that for all solutions satisfy the property that if $k = \lfloor \frac{n+1}2 \rfloor, (k + 1 \mid m + 1)\lor(k-1 \mid m + 1), k -1 \neq 0$
2. http://unsolvedproblems.org/S73.pdf - an algorithmic approach to checking for solutions for the equation, by Robert D. Matson (from unsolvedproblems.org)

Comment: Do you try to prove the weaker statement that there are no more solutions such that $m+1$ has only prime factors $2$ and $3$ ? This weaker statement might be provable but of course does not help to solve the conjecture.

Comment: @Peter I didn't try to prove, just because I felt that the shortage of solutions provides less confidence in generalising it. It would rather be better to conjecture so, as we'd have to group (as in the thread I have posted; hope it was accessible) the numbers and observe the groups to deduce how the solutions from there, if I am right; else we'd need more sophistications.

Comment: @Peter I guess that the greatest advantage here is to have a rough estimate of the prime factorisation of the factorials that follow the conditions of the problem. I think that the facts that we can somehow get about the prime factorisation of $\frac{m-1}2$ (given that $2(m+1)\frac{m-1}2$ is a factorial number) is what we can call the key to solving the problem, it seems.

Comment: I'm not confident in calling that form with $2$s and $3$ the required prime factorisation for $n!$, but as far as I can see, that should be of great help

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129871/a-cross-boundary-chatroom - you can come over to here to post your insights

Comment: If two solutions for $m$ exists the difference of squares must be a difference of factorials.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee that's an obvious thing

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Your first statement about primes seem to be of interest... would you mind restating it?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee do you know of any expression that will yield the difference between factorials??

Comment: The primes thing is just as obvious, two numbers dividing by every prime up to $\frac{n}{2}$ exist in $n!$ and so adding one makes the square not divisible by all of those other squares. You can actually state that until $m>p_{\pi(n)+1}^2$ it must be prime.

Comment: "If two solutions for m exists the difference of squares must be a difference of factorials." - that too depends on the difference between the values of $m$ for which the factorials come up. So if $\exists m_2: m_2^2 = n_2! + 1, m_2 = m_1 + k$, $\exists k : 2mk + k^2 = n_2! - n_1$ for $n_1 < n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$,

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee "The primes thing is just as obvious, two numbers dividing by every prime up to $\frac{n}2$ exist in $n!$ and so adding one makes the square not divisible by all of those other squares. You can actually state that until $m>p^2_{π(n)+1}$ it must be prime." - That's still nice, though...

Comment: "If two solutions for m exists the difference of squares must be a difference of factorials." I had gone through that once earlier when I was more of a simpleton when it comes to thinking about number theory (you'll surely say "Is this boy a fraud?"). Back then I was always into conjecturing without observing and that left me with nonsense. Starting to work on it again seems to have given me a slight insight into how I can deal with numbers. About my claim of having tried that approach before, I used the formula for permutations and ended up writing a quadratic equation::https://bit.ly/3mBK47D

Comment: It's not nonsense the difference between factorials is always divisible by $6$ if both use $n>2$ so your difference of squares must be divisible by $6$ which implies all squares that satisfy the conjecture are $1$ modulo $6$. You're arguing with somebody who turned down nomination for the Abel prize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130325/discussion-between-spectre-and-roddy-macphee).

Comment: $m\bmod 5040 = 1,71,449,559,631,881,1009,1079,1441,1511,1639,1889,1961,2071,2449,2519,2521,2591,2969,3079,3151,3401,3529,3599,3961,4031,4159,4409,4481,4591,4969,5039$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you don't have enough information as is ( which values could work for example). $$n!+1=m^2\implies n!=(m-1)(m+1)$$ But, that tells us is they are $n$-smooth ( whereas $m$ is $n$-rough) , not which factors go in either. We know exactly one $2$ goes in one of them. We can show by the original $$n!+1=m^2$$ that for example $$m^2\bmod 6=1,\forall n>2$$ which limits $m$ by showing it must be $\pm 1\bmod 6$  and so all $3$'s go to one side.  We also can show $m\equiv \pm \bmod 5 \forall n>4$ . Unfortunately this doesn't really help much( in fact I bet my previous comments help as much).  A better fact to use is that $\forall n>9, m\equiv 1,49,51,99\pmod {100}$

Here's the thing,  $m$ is the variable we can easily say something about ( especially meaningfully). $n$ only really has the following ( to my knowledge). If you take $n$ to be an odd square, only $1$ of $n-1,n$  , can work. If $$(n-1)!+1=m_1^2$$  then $$n!+n=(\sqrt{n}m_1)^2$$ but then $$n!+1=m_2^2$$ implies that $$m_2^2-(\sqrt{n}m_1)^2<n$$ Further, the difference of squares is even, and therefore the jump between consecutive squares is under half of $n$ . This implies the smaller base is less than 1 quarter of $n$ . But $m$ grows faster than $n$ . Contradiction.  But that saves no work unless you find a new $n$

And there are values of $n$ that have simple checks :

$$p=n+1$$ with $p$ prime has to have $p$ a Wilson prime.
$$p=n+2$$ needs $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod 8$  by quadratic residues.

There are probably others.

Comment: I hadn't known what a smooth number is but I referred to Wikipedia before talking this: I believe my way of grouping the prime factors will be of help in not thinking about the $n$-roughness of $m$, as we primarily focus on the prime factorisation of $n$ rather than $m$....

Comment: It's that we'll try and make use of this prime factorisation and end up somewhere?? I guess I made the initial equation more Diophantine and harder to solve by bringing in $x$ and $y$ (harder for me as I have never been to such levels of solving Diophantine equations) ?? lol

Comment: Do we even know anything about $n$ which work, other than the next one being greater than $100000$ ?

Comment: no, we don't know anything about that...

Comment: I hope you can understand that I am no trying to argue with you, but it's my being a beginner that is causing this trouble. Yet I'm passionate about this problem that I wish to work on this without losing focus on my ambition in life...

Comment: Kermit rose was mostly stating this, just because the current $m$ are all $5$ mod $6$ doesn't mean they all have to be. Strong law of small numbers is a theorem you'll run into a lot.

Comment: Hey!!! That could be one thing that is preventing another solution to the problem!!! Another (possible) breakthrough!!

Comment: let's move over to the chat link we made for ourselves... that should do good to keep this place sufficiently free of comments

Comment: In fact https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2020_October_5 suggest the search limit for $n$ has exceeded $10^9$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130359/discussion-between-spectre-and-roddy-macphee).